# nextJS : getStaticProps function in dynamic routing is never called

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm trying to create a nextJS app and I have to create dynamics routes. I'm on `Next.js v13.3.4` and I'm using experimental `appDir`.

Here is my file :

```
@\app\projects\[project_slug]\page.tsx

import projects from "@/constants/projects"; //json with my projects information
import Project from "@/constants/projectInterface"; //interface for project objects
import slugify from "@/work/slugify";
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from 'next';
import type { InferGetStaticPropsType } from 'next'

export default function ProjectPage({
  project,
}: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) {
  if (!project) {
    return (
       <div>Loading...</div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{project.title}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function getAllProjectsPaths() {
  return projects.map((project) => {
    return {
      params: {
        project_slug: slugify(project.slug),
      },
    };
  });
}

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  console.log('getStaticPaths called');
  const paths = getAllProjectsPaths();
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

function getProjectBySlug(slug: string | string[]): Project {
  return projects.find((project) => slugify(project.slug) === slug);
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  console.log('getStaticProps called');
  let project = getProjectBySlug(context);
  return { props: { project } };
};
```

The fact is that I never get `getStaticProps called` prompt in the console and the page always shows `Loading...`.

I saw that the `getStaticProps` function must be called inside a page. I think it's my case here (I'm in app/projects/[project_slug] folder and my file name is page.tsx).

Has someone an idea of why and how solves this ?

Thanks for helping !

Comment: getStaticProps is no longer works in app router mechanism, please check this:

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#static-site-generation-getstaticprops

Comment: GetStaticPaths and GetStaticProps were replaced in app directory with [getStaticParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params) and [server actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#step-6-migrating-data-fetching-methods)